# Override body selector when using CssResource

Tags: css, gwt

I am using a CssResource contained within a ClientBundle according to this guide:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#cssfiles

I am accessing the styles from my UiBinder xml according to this guide using ui:with:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_an_external_resource

This works great for accessing my css using class on html elements or styleName on GWT widgets. However, I would like to override the body selector, how can I accomplish that?

This worked great when I previously used  tag within my html-file or when I pointed to the css within my GWT module xml. But since this was depracted I switched to only using CssResource. Now my own body selector is not used and the one from GWT Standard Theme is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found two solutions myself for this:

1. Add @external to the body CSS selector to suppress selector obfuscation, according to this guide:
   http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes

   @external body;
   body {
   my style
   }
2. Add an id to the body, grab the element using GWTs DOM.getElementById and add the style.

   Element body = DOM.getElementById("bodyId");
       body.addClassName(AppResources.layout().body());

Hope this can help other in the same situation.

Comment: You don't need the @external annotation for the body element. @external is only necessary for unobfuscated class names, not element names.